# Python: Break statements for while blocks

Tags: python

```
import random
def get_num ():
return random.randrange (999,9999)

print ("{}".format (get_num ()))


 def get_user_input():
   while True:
    user_input = input 
    print("Please enter a four digit number")

   return user_input
   if False:
       print ("Length of string:" , len (str))
```

Here in this piece of coding I am trying to make a random 4 digit number which will tell user whether or not s/he has guessed the right number (essentially),
specifically though: It will tell the user (at the end of the game) if s/he has guessed certain digits correctly but not which position.

I want 'break' statement to be fitted into this which will separate the while block from the if False. How do I do this correctly? I have tried maany times but I have 4 problems:

1- I don't know where to insert the break

2- When I run the program it doesn't print the second print function.

3- When I run the program it doesn't tell me the length of the string so I don't know if the user is even enterring the correct number of digits.

4- How do I set a limit on python (i.e. how many goes a player can have before the game ends?

Comment: You need to read **basic** python syntax rules and statements. There's many small mistakes here. Consider googling python tutorials and attempting to fix it yourself. That's the best way to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are new to programming and this may be one of your very first codes. It would be great if you start by learning syntax of programming language which you have decided to use as well as working of loops, return statements, etc. I personally preferred reading any basic programming language book. For your case, it would be any book of python which is for beginners. For the sake of completeness, i have added the below code which is probably not exactly what you asked for:

```
import random
def get_num():
    return random.randrange (999,9999)

def get_user_input():
    user_input = int(input())
    return user_input

while True:
    comp_num = get_num()
    print("The computer gave: {}".format(comp_num))

    print("Your turn:")
    user_num = get_user_input()

    if user_num == comp_num:
        print("Done it!")
        break
    else:
        print("No, it's different. Try again!")
        print()
```

In the above code, there are two functions and a while loop. One of the functions takes input from the user while the other generates a random number. The `while` loop is set to run for infinite iterations in case the user doesn't give the same input as the computer. As soon as the user gives the same input as the computer (which is displayed on the screen before he is asked to give input), the `if condition` evaluates to `true`, some things are printed and the `break` statement breaks the loop. And since, there is no further code, the program terminates